# How to make footer stick to the bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem with my footer. I am trying to force it to the bottom, but it always looks ugly.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="footertext">About Us:</h3>
        <br>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <center>
              <img src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/w8lycl.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="the-brains">
              <br>
              <h4 class="footertext">Programmer</h4>
              <p class="footertext">You can thank all the crazy programming here to this guy.<br>
            </center>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <center>
              <img src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/2z7enpc.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="...">
              <br>
              <h4 class="footertext">Artist</h4>
              <p class="footertext">All the images here are hand drawn by this man.<br>
            </center>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <center>
              <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/307n6ux.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="...">
              <br>
              <h4 class="footertext">Designer</h4>
              <p class="footertext">This pretty site and the copy it holds are all thanks to this guy.<br>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use

```
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

but in that case my text ,which is located over the footer, get overlapped by footer

Here is css I used:

```
    #footer {
padding-top: 100px
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Sets the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 280px;
  background: 
  /* color overlay */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(240, 212, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* image to overlay */
    url(222.png);
}
.footertext {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

[Here is what I mean by ugly. I did try to set html and body height as 100% in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4y6U.jpg)

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap please add the tag to your question

Comment: use z-index for the overlapping problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please show us what you mean by "looks ugly" so we can help you, because we can't really understand your issue.

I'd say the problem **could** be in what the parent of `#footer` div.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: @Incognito If you want to use `position: absolute` remember that your `#footer` div will be placed at the bottom it's parent. If the parent is body, it should stay at the bottom of the page.
The way I see it though, you don't need to use absolute positioning as you can simply place the `#footer` div as the last children of body (you don't need to specify `height: 100%` on body)

Answer (score 1):

I think you only have to change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` or `position: fixed;` for the div to stay at the bottom (depending on what behaviour you exactly expect).

Side note, don't use the tag `<center>` because it's now deprecated, use CSS instead (`text-align: center`).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon after padding-top: 100px . You can also try position:fixed instead of position:absolute. An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Its `<div class="footer navbar fixed-bottom">`

not `<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">`

you mistypes a `-`